# group function is not allowed here when run complex query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

when I run the following Query in SQL Developer, which is used to calculate the number of total seconds, number of seconds in Friday day,number of seconds from 00:00:00 to 07:30:00 for each call

```
with finala as (
                    select CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID, sum(sec) secs, nvl(sum(fri),0) fris, nvl(sum(mrn),0) mrns
                    from (
                         select CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID, (least(E_DATE, dt+1)-greatest(S_DATE, dt))*24*60*60 sec, case when trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') = 4 then (least(dt+1, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60 end fri, case when (((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)>0 and trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') <> 4) then ((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60) end mrn
                         from (
                              select CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID, S_DATE, E_DATE, trunc(S_DATE)+level-1 dt
                              from CONTACTS
                              where CONTACTS.LINE_ID = 2
                              connect by trunc(S_DATE)+level-1<=trunc(E_DATE) 
                              and prior dbms_random.value is not null and prior CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID = CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID
                         )
                    )
                    group by CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID
                    )

                    select LINE_ID, SUM(secs) into all_seconds ,SUM(fris) into friday_seconds ,SUM(mrns)into twelve_to_seven_second from finala
                    group by LINE_ID;
```

where `all_seconds` and `friday_seconds` and `twelve_to_seven_second` are variables to hold final data,

but the compiler give error

`ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"`

@ `select LINE_ID, SUM(secs) into all_seconds ,SUM(fris) into friday_seconds ,SUM(mrns)into twelve_to_seven_second from finala` line

why ?

[EDIT] as suggested in the answer, but still the same error :

```
select LINE_ID, SUM(secs) into all_seconds ,SUM(fris) into friday_seconds ,SUM(mrns)into twelve_to_seven_second
                from (
                  with finala as (
                    select CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID, sum(sec) secs, nvl(sum(fri),0) fris, nvl(sum(mrn),0) mrns
                    from (
                         select CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID, (least(E_DATE, dt+1)-greatest(S_DATE, dt))*24*60*60 sec, case when trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') = 4 then (least(dt+1, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60 end fri, case when (((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)>0 and trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') <> 4) then ((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60) end mrn
                         from (
                              select CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID, S_DATE, E_DATE, trunc(S_DATE)+level-1 dt
                              from CONTACTS
                              where CONTACTS.LINE_ID = 2
                              connect by trunc(S_DATE)+level-1<=trunc(E_DATE) 
                              and prior dbms_random.value is not null and prior CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID = CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID
                         )
                    )
                    group by CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID
                    )
                select LINE_ID,secs,fris,mrns from finala
                ) 
                group by LINE_ID;
```

Comment: @GuillaumeF. can you please put you suggestion  as answer ?

Comment: I deleted my answer since it wasn't helping. Unless Oracle allows it, you can't have more than one `into table` per select.

Comment: I want to get the result into variables, then insert them using `insert into` in another table, can I do that ?

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO ..` can be only used in PL/SQL block. You can't run such query directly in SQL Developer (as SQL query) without declaring all variables. Furthermore, you are using bad syntax with multiple `INTO` ->:`SELECT x INTO  y, p INTO q ..,`, the correct syntax contains only one INTO:  `SELECT expression-list INTO variable-list`, see this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm

Comment: If you just want to insert those values, you can use `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement - see the syntax here: [INSERT techonthenet](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php).

Comment: Why do you want them as variables (in a PL/SQL block?) before inserting into another table? Your query will return multiple rows, unless you only have one line ID, so you're looking at a collection rather than just scalar variables anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A little reformatting shows what the issue is:

```
select LINE_ID, SUM(secs) into all_seconds,
       SUM(fris) into friday_seconds,
       SUM(mrns) into twelve_to_seven_second
  from (with finala as (select CONTACT_ID,
                               LINE_ID,
                               sum(sec) secs,
                               nvl(sum(fri),0) fris,
                               nvl(sum(mrn),0) mrns
                          from (select CONTACT_ID,
                                       LINE_ID,
                                       (least(E_DATE, dt+1)-greatest(S_DATE, dt))*24*60*60 sec,
                                       case
                                         when trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') = 4
                                           then (least(dt+1, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60
                                       end fri,
                                       case
                                         when (((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)>0 and
                                               trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') <> 4)
                                           then ((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)
                                       end mrn
                                  from (select CONTACT_ID,
                                               LINE_ID,
                                               S_DATE,
                                               E_DATE,
                                               trunc(S_DATE)+level-1 dt
                                          from CONTACTS
                                          where CONTACTS.LINE_ID = 2
                                          connect by trunc(S_DATE)+level-1<=trunc(E_DATE) and
                                                     prior dbms_random.value is not null and
                                                     prior CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID = CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID))
                          group by CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID)
        select LINE_ID,secs,fris,mrns
          from finala) 
  group by LINE_ID;
```

You can't have multiple `INTO` clauses, as shown in your outer-most query. I suspect this was a typo and that you meant `AS` instead of INTO

```
select LINE_ID,
       SUM(secs) AS ALL_SECONDS,
       SUM(fris) AS FRIDAY_SECONDS,
       SUM (mrns) AS TWELVE_TO_SEVEN_SECOND
  from (with finala as (select CONTACT_ID,
                               LINE_ID,
                               sum(sec) secs,
                               nvl(sum(fri),0) fris,
                               nvl(sum(mrn),0) mrns
                          from (select CONTACT_ID,
                                       LINE_ID,
                                       (least(E_DATE, dt+1)-greatest(S_DATE, dt))*24*60*60 sec,
                                       case
                                         when trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') = 4
                                           then (least(dt+1, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60
                                       end fri,
                                       case
                                         when (((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)>0 and
                                               trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') <> 4)
                                           then ((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)
                                       end mrn
                                  from (select CONTACT_ID,
                                               LINE_ID,
                                               S_DATE,
                                               E_DATE,
                                               trunc(S_DATE)+level-1 dt
                                          from CONTACTS
                                          where CONTACTS.LINE_ID = 2
                                          connect by trunc(S_DATE)+level-1<=trunc(E_DATE) and
                                                     prior dbms_random.value is not null and
                                                     prior CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID = CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID))
                          group by CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID)
        select LINE_ID,secs,fris,mrns
          from finala) 
  group by LINE_ID
```

If I misunderstood and you really meant `INTO` you'll need to provide a variable to hold the resulting `LINE_ID` value as well, as in:

```
select LINE_ID,
       SUM(secs),
       SUM(fris),
       SUM (mrns)
  INTO nLINE_ID,
       ALL_SECONDS,
       FRIDAY_SECONDS,
       TWELVE_TO_SEVEN_SECOND
  from (with finala as (select CONTACT_ID,
                               LINE_ID,
                               sum(sec) secs,
                               nvl(sum(fri),0) fris,
                               nvl(sum(mrn),0) mrns
                          from (select CONTACT_ID,
                                       LINE_ID,
                                       (least(E_DATE, dt+1)-greatest(S_DATE, dt))*24*60*60 sec,
                                       case
                                         when trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') = 4
                                           then (least(dt+1, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60
                                       end fri,
                                       case
                                         when (((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)>0 and
                                               trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw') <> 4)
                                           then ((least(dt+7.5/24, E_DATE) - greatest(dt, S_DATE)) * 24*60*60)
                                       end mrn
                                  from (select CONTACT_ID,
                                               LINE_ID,
                                               S_DATE,
                                               E_DATE,
                                               trunc(S_DATE)+level-1 dt
                                          from CONTACTS
                                          where CONTACTS.LINE_ID = 2
                                          connect by trunc(S_DATE)+level-1<=trunc(E_DATE) and
                                                     prior dbms_random.value is not null and
                                                     prior CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID = CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID))
                          group by CONTACT_ID,LINE_ID)
        select LINE_ID,secs,fris,mrns
          from finala) 
  group by LINE_ID
```

Best of luck.